# Как удалить всё содержимое из библиотеки в Python

Tags: python, instapy

Я установил библиотеку, в которой установились ещё библиотеки (речь идёт об **InstaPy**). Как удалить её вместе с ними?

Comment: `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` попробуй в корневой папке проекта

Comment: Если тебя именно InstaPy интересует, тогда `pip uninstall instapy`